# ggplot2 timeseries plot through night with non-ordered values

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
a = c(22,23,00,01,02) #hours from 22 in to 2 in morning next day
b = c(4,8,-12,3,5) #some values
df = data.frame(a,b)
```

When I plot this data with ggplot2 it sorts the first column `a`, but I don't want it to be sorted.

The code used in ggplot2 is `ggplot(df, aes(a,b)) + geom_line()`

[image: ggplot plot of timeseries and data]

In this case, the X-axis is sorted and they are providing wrong results like

hour 0 consists of value 4, and the truth is that hour 22 consist of value 4

Comment: try converting the times to time objects: `as.POSIXct(c("22", "23", "00", "01", "02"), format = "%H")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R needs to somehow know that what you provide in vector "a" is a time. I have changed your vector slightly to give R the necessary information:

```
a = as.POSIXct(c("0122","0123","0200","0201","0202"), format="%d%H") 
# hours from 22 in to 2 in morning next day (as strings)
# the day is arbitrary but must be provided
b = c(4,8,-12,3,5) #some values
df = data.frame(a,b)
ggplot(df, aes(a,b)) + geom_line()
```

[image: Plot with values ordered by correct time]

You can use paste() to glue days and hours together automatically (e.g. paste(day,22,sep=""))